# Display All Records in SQL Server Query, while Conditionally Excluding Joined Records

Tags: sql, database, conditional-statements, left-join

In a left outer join, how can I always ensure that I get all of the records in my left table (with values in my right table being null when matches don't exist), AND be able to conditionally exclude records from the right table (such as only joining when right table "active" column is set to 1 or match doesn't exist).  When I conditionality exclude records from the right table, it excludes the joined records from my left table as well.

Example of my query:

```
SELECT people.personID, people.name, documents.documentID, documents.score FROM people 
LEFT OUTER JOIN documents ON people.personID = documents.personID 
WHERE (documents.active = 1 OR documents.active IS NULL)
```

This will show all of my people records, except where there is only one matched document that has "active" column value of 0, in which case it excludes the ENTIRE people record for that match, when I want it to still display the people record, but have the matched document records set to null when active is set to 0.  Preferably, I would like to avoid "CASE WHEN" type language, but will do it if that's the only way.

Answer (score 1):

You can have condition for documents in join statement:

```
SELECT people.personID, people.name, documents.documentID, documents.score 
FROM people 
LEFT OUTER JOIN documents ON people.personID = documents.personID AND documents.active = 1
```

or filter is subquery:

```
SELECT people.personID, people.name, documents.documentID, documents.score 
FROM people 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM documents WHERE documents.active = 1) AS documents 
ON people.personID = documents.personID
```